# Django is only extending the base.html template in 1 html file

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I run into an extremely annoying problem that no one has nearly a solution for. I've lost hours on it and unfortunately I can't get it working. This is the problem:

I am trying to extend a base.html file into 2 different html files. For some reason it is possible to extend it in home.html but not in pakbon.html.

Below you can see my folder structure (It also doesn't work if I put the files into the same folder):

[image: Folder structure]

Below you can see my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
path("", views.home, name="home"),
path("pakbon/", views.pakbon, name="pakbon")
]
```

Below you can see my views.py:

```
def index(request):
return render(request, "main/base.html", {})

@login_required
def home(request):
    return render(request, "main/home.html", {})

def pakbon(request):
    return render(request, "pakbonsysteem/pakbon.html", {})
```

My base.html:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
--- Some HTML
</head>
<body data-background-color="{{info.mode}}">

--- Some HTML

    {% endfor %}
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    {% else %}
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=/login">
    {% endif %}

</body>
</html>
```

My home.html:

```
{% extends 'main/base.html' %}

{% block content %}

--- Some HTML

{% endblock %}
```

My pakbon.html:

```
{% extends 'main/base.html' %}

{% block content %}

--- Some HTML code

{% endblock %}
```

Image from home.html:
[image]

Image from pakbon.html:
[image]

They should both show the same layout, only home.html shows a table and pakbon.html shows a div with some information and javascript, which you see in the image above. However, this doesn't happen.. He just doesn't extend the base.html file in the pakbon.html file. I can also see this because the javascript is not working either. I couldn't figure it out after days of wasting it.. Would be very happy if someone can help me with this.

Comment: try clear browswer history.

Comment: also see if ou have typo in your  pakbon.html: especially the first line {% extends...

Comment: Try clearing browser cache. It happens a lot in some browsers. Also try different browser. If that works, something is wrong with default browser.

Comment: @Nikz Jon, Thanks for your message, I have cleared the cache several times and tried various browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Edge, IE). Unfortunately nothing works :(

Comment: @ha-neul, Thanks for you message, there is not a single typo in the HTML. I also copied the home.html and pasted it into pakbon.html. Even then it doesn't extend the base.html file.

Answer (score 0):

Check your settings.py file for this constant:

```
    TEMPLATES = [ 
        {
            'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
            'DIRS': ['abc/123',
                     'myfiles/foo/bar'],
            'APP_DIRS': True,
            # more stuff here
        }

]
```

Make sure the folder with base.html is listed there.

Also try moving base.html to the other directory to see if it works and the other one stops working. That will give you some insight.

Comment: Thanks for your message, I tried several paths there: `'DIRS': ['main/templates', 'C:/Users/---/PycharmProjects/projecta/main/templates', str(BASE_DIR) + '/templates/', os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'), ],` unfortunately this doesn't work either :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your `pakbon.html` in the same folder as your home.html.

It looks like `main` is one of your `app`. In this case, all your main's template files should reside in

`main` ---> `templates`--> `main`.

django will not recognize the `pakbonsysteem` folder just under main/templates folder. it will look for `main/templates/main`

**Of cause, you need to change how you refer it in your views.py**

`'main/pakbon.html'`